# Running vim-ruby-debugger on MacVim in OS X 10.10

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, vim

Spent all day trying to make it works.
Installed like described in readme.

This shell call:

```
rdebug-vim --file /Users/aleksandrkunin/.vim/tmp/ruby_debugger --output /Users/aleksandrkunin/.vim/tmp/ruby_debugger_output --socket /var/folders/p9/dq06c2dn72nbbk45qdc5yx1h0000gp/T/vLSSici/17 --logger_file /Users/aleksandrkunin/.vim/tmp/ruby_debugger_log --debug_mode 0 --vim_executable mvim --vim_servername VIM --separator ++vim-ruby-debugger-separator++ -- '/Users/aleksandrkunin/Documents/rails_projects/tracks_dev/script/rails' server
```

Cause this error:

```
Users/aleksandrkunin/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/debugger-xml-0.4.1/lib/byebug/commands/frame.rb:12:in `alias_method': undefined method `get_pr_arguments' for module `Byebug::FrameFunctions' (NameError)
    from /Users/aleksandrkunin/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/debugger-xml-0.4.1/lib/byebug/commands/frame.rb:12:in `<module:FrameFunctions>'
    from /Users/aleksandrkunin/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/debugger-xml-0.4.1/lib/byebug/commands/frame.rb:2:in `<module:Byebug>'
    from /Users/aleksandrkunin/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/debugger-xml-0.4.1/lib/byebug/commands/frame.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/aleksandrkunin/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /Users/aleksandrkunin/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /Users/aleksandrkunin/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/debugger-xml-0.4.1/lib/debugger_xml.rb:5:in `block in <top (required)>'
    from /Users/aleksandrkunin/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/debugger-xml-0.4.1/lib/debugger_xml.rb:5:in `each'
    from /Users/aleksandrkunin/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/debugger-xml-0.4.1/lib/debugger_xml.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/aleksandrkunin/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /Users/aleksandrkunin/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /Users/aleksandrkunin/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/debugger-xml-0.4.1/bin/rdebug-vim:15:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/aleksandrkunin/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/bin/rdebug-vim:23:in `load'
    from /Users/aleksandrkunin/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/bin/rdebug-vim:23:in `<main>'
```

Is it possible to run? Is there another way for visual debugging in VIM?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is that you're trying to use a gem that says it's for Ruby >= 1.9 with Ruby 2+.

rdebug does not work with Ruby 2.0+, only with Ruby in the 1.9 range. The documentation is confusing but that's how it is.

> ... This is a new version of the plugin, which uses debugger-xml gem, and works only with Ruby >= 1.9....

Look at the revision history of rdebug and you can see it hasn't been updated in a while.

With 2.1.1 you're using byebug, which doesn't implement the necessary call to work with Vim, hence the message:

```
undefined method `get_pr_arguments' for module `Byebug::FrameFunctions' (NameError)
```

Your choices are:

- Revert to Ruby 1.9.3-p551, which is the latest of that series and install rdebug.
- Stop trying to use vim-rdebug and learn to use byebug in its standalone mode, which is a more traditional debugger and works nicely. (Alternately you could use Pry and pry-debug.)

Comment: But what confuse me more: first is in debugger-xml I've seen `if RUBY_VERSION > 2.0` and second is module `Byebug::FrameFunctions` has this method

Comment: You're right. Author said it will support Ruby 2.0+ soon, but now it doesn't

Comment: You can try use both `debugger-xml` and `byebug` from master. Support should be ready, we just need some gem releases. It would actually be a good thing that someone tries it and gives feedback before we release. :)

Comment: @deivid, could you please help me to set it up with logging?

Comment: @AleksandrK. What you mean? Running vim-ruby-debugger with byebug support? If it's that, I'm going to contact vim-ruby-debugger author soon to try the new feature. I'll let you know!